# ie8 doesnt catch errors in parent iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-8

Clean example.
**main document:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function catchError(fn) {
        try {
            fn();
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log('catched in catchError '+e.message);
        }
    }
</script>
<iframe src="child.html" id="child"></iframe>
```

**child.html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function throwError() {
            throw new Error('testing');
        }
        parent.catchError(throwError);
</script>
```

All other browsers (ie9 including) properly provide error to catch block. IE8 just dont do it and log the error as if try-catch block was missing.

Do you have any ideas, or fixes? Maybe its matter of ie8 settings? Maybe you can provide a workaround?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you put the `try`/`catch` around the call to `parent.catchError(throwError);`?

Comment: it catches error, but due to some iframe data sharing policies the error object is empty. Nevertheless I need to catch it in parent scope.